# MariaDB opens instead of MySQL in cmd prompt

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been using XAMPP for MySQL which works fine when I am using in browser but if I open MySQL in command-line it opens MariaDB instead of MySQL. Let me know the reason soon.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like Xamp now ships with MariaDB. Check out this article for more information

> https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20151019.html

The `MYSQL` apache extension works with `MariaDB` so although it seems apache is using MYSQL i think it is connecting to your `MariaDB` server.

I wouldn't worry too much. MariaDB runs and works almost identical to `MYSQL`. What sort of concerns do you have running MariaDB?

If it is an issue have a look at installing and older version of Xamp that contains `MYSQL` eg

> https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

Comment: Crazy..right. I noticed this recently on my VPS. I am so confused. I used to have a MySQL installed there.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to respond the question , but I also have same problem and  you can use either of these options

1. mysql -u user_name -h host_name mysql  -p
   replace  user_name and host_name with yours
2. mysql -u user_name -h host_name  -p
   Then enter
   Use mysql;
   And that will do it.

Answer (score -1):

That's fine. Try running table fetching commands & it will work fine.
Like "**use tablename**"
"**show table**" etc & it will fetch data from MySQL database only